Wix 301 redirect goes to blank 200 page first instead of directly to page with 404 response
curl -L -s -o /dev/null -q -w "%{http_code}" "https://www.seldelaterre.fr/articles/sdt93/La%20racine%20philosophique%20des%20erreurs%20moderne%20d'apr%c3%a8s%20l'encyclique%20Pascendi"

returns a 200 response (after doing a 301 redirect to convert spaces to dashes).
Then, going to that URL
curl -L -s -o /dev/null -q -w "%{http_code}" "https://www.seldelaterre.fr/articles/sdt93/La-racine-philosophique-des-erreurs-moderne-d'après-l'encyclique-Pascendi"

results in another 200 response.
Then the capital letters in the URLs are down-cased (I think by JavaScript now, not a 301 redirect). Going to that URL
curl -L -s -o /dev/null -q -w "%{http_code}" "https://www.seldelaterre.fr/articles/sdt93/la-racine-philosophique-des-erreurs-moderne-d'apr%C3%A8s-l'encyclique-pascendi"

results in a 404 response.
Why didn't my first curl command lead directly to the 404 page? Instead, it led to a blank page with this HTTP response header:
HTTP/2 200 
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
link: <https://static.parastorage.com/>; rel=preconnect; crossorigin;,<https://static.parastorage.com/>; rel=preconnect;,<https://static.wixstatic.com/>; rel=preconnect; crossorigin;,<https://static.wixstatic.com/>; rel=preconnect;,<https://siteassets.parastorage.com>; rel=preconnect; crossorigin;,
x-wix-request-id: 1717541931.7311331803501922011
cache-control: no-cache
content-language: en
strict-transport-security: max-age=86400
set-cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=1717541932|hJZR7oHeYHJW; Path=/; Domain=www.seldelaterre.fr; Secure; SameSite=None
set-cookie: _wixAB3|18f8d175-a193-4612-bbf3-b81d529a093b=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Tue, 04 Jun 2024 22:58:52 GMT; Path=/articles/sdt93/La-racine-philosophique-des-erreurs-moderne-d%27apr%C3%A8s-l%27encyclique-Pascendi; Domain=.wix.com
set-cookie: ssr-caching=cache#desc=none; Max-Age=20; Expires=Tue, 04 Jun 2024 22:59:12 GMT
age: 0
accept-ranges: bytes
server: Pepyaka
x-content-type-options: nosniff
date: Tue, 04 Jun 2024 22:58:52 GMT
x-served-by: cache-bur-kbur8200109-BUR
x-cache: MISS
vary: Accept-Encoding
server-timing: cache;desc=none
x-seen-by: yvSunuo/8ld62ehjr5B7kA==,1ev8u3tblITHmgXkyGXE9h9slopJdhD+WySraMrpIY8=,m0j2EEknGIVUW/liY8BLLsF6ZK0ExZ9qybsUJ5Iw3hMm++C2XkuTvnlRFg2XiSDL,2d58ifebGbosy5xc+FRalqag29FuAa1WHptO+Noh8iJnix6f4vL+n5l32RNbhUHHoesMMgbx8oYIEwY0tSMogQ==,2UNV7KOq4oGjA5+PKsX47EHFERyhueBkQ7yxR4fBRf5jPZTuGyYqVhtmEIgJUb4w,R8nVwPJv9QJL1m78OROO+DroItHPH0bJpK+qcIvhkd4=,wjXkXN74v+Dcwxj+UalvvnRZ5t7jKcZlbfYMsi/CyYYSO5XmrrCSQNDehIjmfew3yTp1hJea1e+t+7jpJiVdZw==,R8nVwPJv9QJL1m78OROO+BIo20OZsc5GzyTe0hHk5EU=,LoUK8/saGAmOxZWtpubo2n19C13jHjcTxKtq6SVNAu7rId1Tyd8/mPxtSHzXGqDBez7YWFTrjSExzUDyKEcHkSMWfgGvErMqwt4m5psff1M=,R8nVwPJv9QJL1m78OROO+B49mMslzM+0dkPpIVzkhu4=,EGy4zcsvV2XHHiCimAE1z7TJmVgsCJLjkB79aQs0iRkcJWfAx5UvlKTk5vz7UWmwtYMpC0BhkbVEoYljDdSarHNC7atLrALh0mzhWG2mko0=
via: 1.1 google
glb-x-seen-by: bS8wRlGzu0Hc+WrYuHB8QIg44yfcdCMJRkBoQ1h6Vjc=
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000

Is Wix doing JavaScript URL rewriting?
This makes it hard to use curl to find 404 responses / broken links.
